# Почему изображение весит больше при отображении в память, чем исходный файл?

Tags: графика

Собственно, вопрос.

Вот есть файл изображения, который весит 4 мб. Почему этот же файл при загрузке в память, например через GDI+ весит уже в районе 50 мб?

Comment: Потому что файл сжатый, а всякие разные манипуляции можно проводить только с несжатыми данными

Comment: @andreymal, ответы - в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy детали реализации GDI+ пусть кто-нибудь другой распишет